# Activate tap to click on touchpad?

Tags: debian, touchpad, lxde, powerpc

I am using Debian 8.6 LXDE on a Powerbook G4 15" 1.67GHz and would like to enable tap to click on the touchpad. It is already double scrolling but tap to click would help to save the ageing mouse button. Two fingered tap for left click would be the icing on the cake, is this possible?

Comment: only this worked for me https://askubuntu.com/a/1053119/130091

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Debian Jessie**

To enable the touchpad tapping permanently , copy the `50-synaptics.conf` file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` then edit it by adding `Option "TapButton1" "1"` .

As root:

```
mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

The `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` should be:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Option "TapButton1" "1"
        Option "TapButton2" "3"
```

Reboot your system

**Debian Stretch and Buster** (updated)

Remove the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package. **(important)**

```
# apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Install `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`:

```
# apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

> In most cases, make sure you have the `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` package installed, and not the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package.

As root:

create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

```
mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

Create the `40-libinput.conf` file:

```
echo 'Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "Tapping" "on"
EndSection' > /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
```

restart your DM; e,g:

```
# systemctl restart lightdm
```

or

```
# systemctl restart gdm3
```

Debian wiki : [Enable tapping on touchpad](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad#Debian_9_.22Stretch.22)

Comment: Is it possible to have two finger tap for "right click"?

Comment: @SimonBaldwin see my edit

Comment: Do I have to be 'root' to do this, or can I sudo it from my usual account?

Comment: There is no xorg.conf in X11                                                                X11$ ls
app-defaults             rgb.txt  Xreset      Xsession.d
default-display-manager  X        Xreset.d    Xsession.options
fonts                    xinit    Xresources  xsm
openbox                  xkb      Xsession    Xwrapper.config

Comment: I made the directory and it worked, even two finger tap for right click. Thank you!

Comment: I think you can restart X instead of the whole system.

Comment: The configuration worked for me (Debian Stretch)! BUT: I agree with Rolf, restarting the whole display led me to loose some pendant work ...

Comment: The stretch part is also working for buster

Comment: @BERA Thank you.  Of course , I will update my answer

Comment: With 2 laptops here it's not working for Buster.

Comment: @GAD3R I later noticed that it was just a setting under "mouse properties" that we've missed. Thank you!

Comment: After trying this I got gdm3 not working any more. I had to dpkg-reconfigure lightdm to be able of open my debian stretch

Comment: If Wayland doesn't use synaptics driver, using libinput instead, then why is the first one installed by default?

Comment: I guess the comparison should be relabeled to something more agnostic such as the difference between the `synaptics` driver's configuration and `libinput`

Answer (score 33):

In recent systems (2017) as many distros are moving to Wayland, synaptics driver is no longer used. Instead, libinput is used.

To enable tap to click on touchpad using libinput create a file in Xorg config:

```
$ touch /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-synaptics-overrides.conf
```

And add the following configuration:

```
Section  "InputClass"
    Identifier  "touchpad overrides"
    Driver "libinput"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option "Tapping" "on"
    Option "TappingButtonMap" "lmr"
EndSection
```

Comment: +1 as this is the only way to get `tap to click` working on `Debian Stretch`.

Comment: Worked for me (Debian Stretch, Gnome 3 X11). Also worth noting that it made more options available in Gnome's mouse setting panel (such as `tap to click`).

Comment: Upvoted using newly enabled tap-to-click on Debian 9.2. (Though this config did something unexpected to the touchpad's acceleration.)

Comment: @pdoherty926 Try adding  Option "AccelProfile" flat, to disable pointer acceleration.

Comment: @GabrielMolina: I did this in a different way before and my computer didn't function properly as before. For example I couldn't open any GUI application as a root user. While now it works smoothly.

Comment: @For me it works to get 1 click. Now I need to have 2 fingers tap as secondary mouse button. How can I do that?

Comment: @Mephisto Try "TappingButtonMap" "lrm"
This option is the mapping for 1, 2 and 3 fingers to left, right, middle click.

Comment: Worked for me, +1. But I called it `99-touchpad-overrides`, as it is generic and my Yoga 370 actually has an Elantech touchpad.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 + xfce: this method worked.

Comment: If Wayland doesn't use synaptics driver, using libinput instead, then why is the first one installed by default?

Comment: i removed `server-xorg-input-synaptics` and reboot and tap to click work again ! in gnome 45

Answer (score 24):

This does the trick for me in similar situation under Debian 8.6 and LXDE:

```
synclient TapButton1=1
```

Above works if synaptics touchpad work with Synaptics Driver `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.

If you are working with `libinput` driver (default driver in many live images):

```
xinput set-prop 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad' 'libinput Tapping Enabled' 1
```

You can use `xinput list-props 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'` to see all available properties that can be adjusted for your TouchPad.

If your system uses `libinput` you can use `xinput` to find out the name of your touchpad device if the above command doesn't work (they aren't all Synaptics). For example:

Output for `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Command to enable clicking:

```
xinput set-prop 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint' 'libinput Tapping Enabled' 1
```

Comment: Yes that works, thank you! Is there a way to make this happen on boot?

Comment: @SimonBaldwin Try to put this line in file `/etc/rc.local` or to `/etc/init.d/rc.local`. PS: If you are happy with this answer, don't forget to accept this answer as a solution.

Comment: Tried adding to both these files but I still have to enable it manually in the terminal after each boot. Is there any other way of enabling it on boot or login?

Comment: @SimonBaldwin Give a look here : https://wiki.lxde.org/en/Autostart

Comment: @SimonBaldwin for two finger right click try this : `$: synclient TapButton2=3 TapButton3=2`. Also by running `synclient` you will see all the options available for touchpad.

Comment: Worked on centos7/64 !!

Answer (score 8):

Using debian Stretch 9.5 with xfce desktop environment .

update : `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`

Add this section:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "Tapping" "on"
EndSection
```

Reboot the system and now tapping should work.

Comment: I did exactly as per the answer (However I created a backup of the file `sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf{,.bak}` before). And it fixed the problems with i3, sddm etc. It's on Debian 9.6.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing on Debian 10.2 XFCE and worked perfectly. I suggest you to "reboot your touchpad" device clicking the Fn+F# button if it exists. In my keyboard the button is #=6. 

Don't try to install another driver for your system, if you can!

Answer (score 3):

On Debian 9.1 (stretch) I ran in the same issue (on an asus laptop). I Used LXDE as George.

If you can't find synclient, install first :

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Then add the following line at the end of `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`:

```
@synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=3 TapButton3=2
```

Reboot and now you can "tap click" and "two fingers tap - right click"

Answer (score 3):

This is my synaptic xorg config and works perfectly on Debian 9.7 (stretch) with **`xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`** package.

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptic.conf
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"

    ## for natural scrolling
    Option "VertScrollDelta"  "-111"
    Option "HorizScrollDelta" "-111"

    ## tap to click
    Option "TapButton1" "1"

    ## two finger tap to Right click
    Option "TapButton2" "3"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, the following simple command did the trick:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Then reboot (or restart display manager).

Comment: 18.04 LTS seems to default to Wayland by default, which may explain why the above command yields an unmet dependency on xserver-xorg-input-synaptics, which isn't installed because xserver-xorg-core isn't installed. I'm scared.

Answer (score 1):

On recent Debian - I'm running Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) - you can turn it using the settings app:

Settings > Mouse & Touchpad > Tap to Click

[image]

Comment: I am happy to upvote your answer. If you could provide an image, even better...

Answer (score 0):

Tapping and other touchpad settings are configured either through XInput2 as "device properties", or through Xorg.conf as settings for the 'libinput' driver.

Replace `Touchpad_Device_Name` with the device name (**not ID number**) that you see in `xinput list`.

`xinput set-prop "Touchpad_Device_Name" "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1`