# How do I disable "tap to click" (touchpad) on KDE5/plasma-based installations? (currently using KDE neon)

Tags: kde, touchpad, kde5, plasma5, tap

I am looking at the System Settings => Input Devices => Touchpad but nothing jumps out.

On Ubuntu/Unity, it is obvious which setting to use when wanting to play around  with "tap to click".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

as answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337008/activate-tap-to-click-on-touchpad/337218)

> To enable the touchpad tapping permanently , copy the
>   `50-synaptics.conf` file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` then edit it by
>   adding `Option "TapButton1" "1"`
>
> ```
> cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
> ```
>
> The `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` should be:
>
> ```
> Section "InputClass"
>         Identifier "touchpad catchall"
>         Driver "synaptics"
>         MatchIsTouchpad "on"
>         Option "TapButton1" "1"
>         Option "TapButton2" "3"
> ```
>
> Reboot your system

in your case set TapButton1 to 0 to look like this

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Option "TapButton1" "0"
```