# Debian 9 mate desktop and touchpad

Tags: debian

I am running in my netbook Debian 9 Mate. Everything works fine, apart from the touchpad. I cannot find a way to make it work. My last try was to remove the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and have only the `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`, but that did not change anything.
Any ideas please?

Comment: What is the output of `xinput --list`?

Comment: Have a look here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337008/activate-tap-to-click-on-touchpad As far as i remember is not a good idea to not use `synaptics` and rely on `libinput`

Comment: hi. i am afraid xinput is not found in my system. bash: xinput: command not found     also, i am using libinput since it is mentioned in https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad#Debian_9_.22Stretch.22   how can i fix the issue please?