# Tap activation for touchpad in Debian 9

Tags: debian, touchpad, tap

I am trying tap activate my touchpad according to this answer [Activate tap to click on touchpad?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337008/activate-tap-to-click-on-touchpad/337009) but the problem is that I don't have a folder `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Create the missing directory with:

```
# mkdir -p /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
```