# Touchpad doesn't work

Tags: touchpad, pop-os

**The problem**

When I try to use my laptop touchpad, nothing happens. It also does not respond to clicks. The keyboard works fine.

**Workarounds**

Using a usb mouse works just fine

**My system**

Acer Aspire 5

Pop!_os 20.10 (I started with 20.04 and upgraded last night. Didn't fix)

```bsh
> uname -a
Linux pop-os 5.8.0-7642-generic #47~1614007149~20.10~82fb226-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 23 02:59:01 UTC  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It does seem to be recognized though...

```bsh
> sudo cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=303f Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN0504:00 04F3:303F Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN0504:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN0504:00/0018:04F3:303F.0001/input/input26
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event18
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

It is also showing up under Virtual core pointer:

```bsh
> xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer DeathAdder V2                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer DeathAdder V2                 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ OLKB Preonic Mouse                        id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ OLKB Preonic Consumer Control             id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0504:00 04F3:303F Mouse               id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0504:00 04F3:303F Touchpad            id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

```bsh
> sudo dmesg | grep ELAN
[    0.886077] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0504:00: supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.886087] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0504:00: supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
[    1.183623] input: ELAN0504:00 04F3:303F Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN0504:00/0018:04F3:303F.0001/input/input5
[    1.183935] input: ELAN0504:00 04F3:303F Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN0504:00/0018:04F3:303F.0001/input/input6
[    1.184274] hid-generic 0018:04F3:303F.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [ELAN0504:00 04F3:303F] on i2c-ELAN0504:00
[    2.513752] usb 1-7: Product: ELAN:Fingerprint
[    2.513753] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: ELAN
[   39.950963] input: ELAN0504:00 04F3:303F Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN0504:00/0018:04F3:303F.0001/input/input25
[   39.951072] input: ELAN0504:00 04F3:303F Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN0504:00/0018:04F3:303F.0001/input/input26
[   39.951163] hid-multitouch 0018:04F3:303F.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [ELAN0504:00 04F3:303F] on i2c-ELAN0504:00
```

Comment: There is often a hardware switch for touchpads have you checked that usally it is something like alt-F5 I know is simple and stupid but need to ask.  Also verify xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is installed.  Also some bios have a touchpad mode in them that needs to be set.

Comment: Élan should work in thé same way as synaptic, please check m'y answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337218/153195