# Magic Trackpad tap-to-click Debian 12 Xfce, how to enable

Tags: debian, xfce, touchpad

[image: Magic Trackpad Debian 12 Xfce Tap touchpad to click]

```
Xfce Version 4.18
GTK Version 3.24.38
Kernel Version 6.1.0-18-amd64
```

First SE question. I tried to comment [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749095/592147) instead but do not have sufficient reputation.

*How do I enable tap-to-click for a Magic Trackpad device in Debian 12/ Xfce?*

The `Tap touchpad to click` setting has no effect and is not persistent. Additionally, right click does not work and there are two device entries. Switching between entries has no effect. The touchpad is connected with a USB cable. It doesn't appear in Bluetooth search.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as expected after a reboot. The duplicate device entry is still there and it doesn't show up in Bluetooth search. Defaults to

- one finger left click
- two finger right click
- double tap to maximize
- double tap and hold to drag
- other things?

Bonus Reboot Fact: I had to reboot again after I crashed my system while trying to record a three finger drag with Input Remapper, a maneuver that is clearly above my pay grade.

Linux!